# Only GPU to CPU transfer with cupy is incredible slow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, cupy

If I have an array on the GPU, it is really slow (order of hundreds of seconds) to copy back an array of shape (20, 256, 256).

My code is the following:

```
import cupy as cp
from cupyx.scipy.ndimage import convolve
import numpy as np

# Fast...
xt = np.random.randint(0, 255, (20, 256, 256)).astype(np.float32)
xt_gpu = cp.asarray(xt)

# Also very fast...
result_gpu = convolve(xt_gpu, xt_gpu, mode='constant')

# Very very very very very slow....
result_cpu = cp.asnumpy(result_gpu)
```

I measured the times using `cp.cuda.Event()` with `record` and `synchronize` to avoid measuring any random times, but is still the same result, the GPU->CPU transfer is incredible slow. However, using PyTorch or TensorFlow this is not the case (out of experience for similar data size/shape)... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be timing it wrong. I modified the code to synchronize between every GPU operation and it seems like the convolution takes the majority of the time with both transfer operations being very fast.

```py
import cupy as cp
from cupyx.scipy.ndimage import convolve
import numpy as np
import time
# Fast...
xt = np.random.randint(0, 255, (20, 256, 256)).astype(np.float32)

t0 = time.time()
xt_gpu = cp.asarray(xt)
cp.cuda.stream.get_current_stream().synchronize()
print(time.time() - t0)

# Also very fast...
t0 = time.time()
result_gpu = convolve(xt_gpu, xt_gpu, mode='constant')
cp.cuda.stream.get_current_stream().synchronize()
print(time.time() - t0)

# Very very very very very slow....
t0 = time.time()
result_cpu = cp.asnumpy(result_gpu)
cp.cuda.stream.get_current_stream().synchronize()
print(time.time() - t0)
```

Output:

```
0.1380000114440918
4.032999753952026
0.0010001659393310547
```

To me it seems like you are not actually synchronizing between calls when you tested it. Until the transfer back to a numpy array all operations are simply queued up and seem to finish instantly without the synchronize calls. This would lead to the measured GPU->CPU transfer time actually being the time for the convolution and the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem, I found that accessing Float64 data is way faster than Float32, maybe you can try to .astype(float64).